# What Scripting Targets exist for iTunes?

Tags: cocoa, itunes, appstore-sandbox

Apple has a nice documented [Technical Q&A page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1802/_index.html) for implementing scripting targets for Mail.app.  However, even though scripting targets also work for iTunes, there isn't a comprehensive list of available scripting targets.

Does anybody know how to find this list?  The WWDC 2012 session on Secure Automation mentions a few, but it isn't comprehensive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In OS X 10.9 Mavericks, you can view the `com.apple.iTunes.sdef` file at `/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Resources`.  This lists the scripting target access group associated with each AppleScript command.

There are six access groups:

```
com.apple.iTunes.device
com.apple.iTunes.library.read
com.apple.iTunes.library.read-write
com.apple.iTunes.playback
com.apple.iTunes.podcast
com.apple.iTunes.user-interface
```

Comment: In general: yes. There will likely be bugs and sandboxing issues, however. What exactly are you trying to do?