# Entitlement Keys/Access Groups for Scripting Targets

Tags: appstore-sandbox, scripting-bridge, entitlements, applescript-objc

I can't seem to figure out how to identify what entitlement keys are available for a given app. How does one query an application for its entitlement keys?

Example:
iTunes has these entitlement keys: *com.apple.iTunes.playerInfo*, *com.apple.iTunes.library.read-write*, & *com.apple.iTunes.playback*

But if I didn't already know this, how could I have retrieved these keys from the iTunes application? What about 3rd-party (non-Apple) apps? Where would one find entitlement keys, if there are any, for those?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to look at iTunes's scripting definition (`sdef`) file. iTunes's is in a weird place (`/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/com.apple.iTunes.sdef`, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21345593/105717)).  If you look inside Mail's (or a 3rd party app's) package, and browse to `Contents/Resources` directory, you should see an `sdef` file there too.

You can also use the AppleScript Editor's **Open Dictionary** menu item and command-click on the proxy icon in the title bar to view a temporary copy of the `sdef`, which works the same way for iTunes and any other app.

Once in the `sdef` file (using any text editor), you want to look for all of the `<access-group />` tags to see which scripting targets the app exposes.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I also found that running this in Terminal worked as well (just replace the app name, obviously): sdef /Applications/Mail.app > mail.sdef.xml